# UGC - Comments opened as Read-Only via Control Room

Tags: 2011, ugc

When I open a comment via the Control Room, it appears to open in read-only mode.
To clarify I'm doing the following in the Tridion GUI:

Control Room > Community > Show all comments > Select a comment > Open Item

I confirmed read-only status after looking in the code and trying `$display.getItem().isReadOnly();` in the console, which returned `true`.

The problem is the interface still lets you click "Edit Comment" and the Delete button even though nothing happens becuase its read-only!

[image: Comment view]

Our client now immediately believes something is broken - and I can understand why!
We've documented how to use the Control Room to filter & find comments - yet when they get to the comment list to delete one, they're left clicking an "X" button that does nothing - bad.

**Is this behaviour configurable, so that opening an comment does so in an editable mode?**

The only workaround I can find is to locate the component with comments normally, localise at our website publication (the same ID our app uses to record comments) and then open it.

The comment list is now fully editable. But this leaves our users having to flick between the Control Room to find components and then back to Tridion to localise/open.

NB - I tried *Open & Localize this item* but this seems to stop the Comments from loading full stop. I had to localize first, then open the component.

NB - All the above is also true if you use the *User Generated Content* node under a publication. Open from here - read-only.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? Could it have been that the Component was checked-out or that the user didn't have UGC Rights within the parent Publication?

Comment: Yes Jon. There's a hot fix that's part of HR2 SDL support made available to us that addresses it.

Comment: would be nice if you post your solution as an answer and accept it, so this question has an accepted answer which is useful as a reference for new users which might have a similair question.